# Cannot display array on view load

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode

I am trying to display the contents of an array by calling a method in a different class that loops through the array and appends a string. However it is not displaying anything when i segue to that view. I have added breakpoints to check if there is anything in the array and the data is definitely being stored inside.
Is there a reason why this is happening?

Portrait class where i want all the array contents to be displayed

portrait.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Brain.h"


@interface PortraitTape : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *equationView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Brain *brain;
@end
```

portrait.m

```
#import "PortraitTape.h"

@interface PortraitTape ()


@end

@implementation PortraitTape

@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize equationView;

- (Brain *) brain{

if (!_brain)_brain =[[Brain alloc]init];
return _brain;
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *tape;

    tape = [self.brain gettape];
    equationView.text = tape;
}
```

Brain.m class method that hashe array and data is being inserted into. This method is called in the portrait class.

```
-(NSString*) gettape {

    NSMutableString *tape = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for(NSString * myStr in _equation) {
        //tape = myStr;
        [tape appendFormat:@"\n%@",myStr];

    }

    return tape;
}
```

Comment: and your `equationView`, are you sure that is init'd and on the screen? is it a `UILabel`, `UITextField`, etc.? is your @synthesize call needed? And you should rename `gettape` to `getTape` to match camel case convention

Comment: Are you ever initilizing `self.brain` ?

Comment: ^ He should actually probably just rename it to `tape` to match iOS convention. "`get`" is never used as part of a selector name.

Comment: @random I have added my .h file to the question and have added more code to my question

Comment: Are you creating or assigning `Brain *brain` from somewhere? With what you have now, `brain` is never initialized and thus is `null` which would be why it's returning nothing.

Comment: How and where do you create _equation? If you log tape as the last line in gettape, does it log correctly?